# Restrict / Ignore domain cookies in http domain request

Tags: nginx, cookies, subdomain

I have a client domain, let's say `example.com` which is setting cookies with domain `.example.com` and those are not under my control as other client applications are setting these cookies and I can't modify them.

My application is hosted under the subdomain - `demo.example.com`. I am setting two cookies in this subdomain. Whenever the browser sends an Http request to the Nginx server, it's taking all the cookies within the subdomain as well as from the domain.
Right now, there are a lot of cookies from the domain which is increasing the size of the header and causing a break at Nginx(returning 404).

Is there any way by which I can restrict the domain cookies from getting into the subdomain request? These domain cookies are not under my control.

I tried modifying the request header cookies before sending the request, but the browser doesn't allow that. In my angularJs code, I tried to modify the headers like this

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function() {
  return {
    'request': function (config) {
      config.headers = config.headers || {};
      config.headers.Cookies = ""
      return config;
    };
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

It throws an error - Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie".
Is there any way to handle this situation at the browser level?

At Nginx level, I tried to fix this problem by following this link - https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,252944,253012#msg-253012 and it seems to be working fine. But is there any other by which I can ignore domain cookies and keep only subdomain cookies in my request?